# Trading Arceus Into Pokemon Home / Newer Games?

Tags: pokemon-series, emulation, pokemon-home

According to multiple sources online, Arceus was (briefly) officially made available, though only via Nintendo events in North America (because America is the only country in the world that plays Pokémon games, right?)... Also according to multiple sources online, Arceus can be caught in 'Pokémon: Diamond Version' / 'Pokémon: Pearl Version' [through sudo-legitimate methods, albeit with some help from an 'Action Replay' device](https://www.wikihow.com/Catch-Arceus) (apparently Nintendo were intending to make Arceus' availability official, but later changed their minds, leaving the code in the game).

And according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/emf3rq/pokemon_transfer_process_to_home/), one can theoretically trade Pokémon from the first-generation games ('Pokémon: Blue Version', 'Pokémon: Red Version' and 'Pokémon: Yellow Version') all the way to the seventh-generation games ('Pokémon Shield' and 'Pokémon Sword'), provided one is using the 'digital' (Virtual Console) version of the first-generation games... Does this mean that one could theoretically catch Arceus using the sudo-legitimate method described above, and then trade him or her forward to later generations or 'Pokémon Home'?

Secondary to this question, is it possible to trade Pokémon from emulators to the 'physical' games or their 'digital' (Virtual Console) counterpart (where released by Nintendo)? I have most of the 'physical' Pokémon games, but assuming trading Arceus forward is theoretically possible, it would be a lot easier to do if I was using an emulator...

Looking forward to hearing people's thoughts on this, particularly given that most rumors are saying Arceus probably won't be catchable in 'Pokémon Legends: Arceus' (despite playing a central role in the storyline).

Comment: Consider that hacked/glitched Pokemon can be blocked when trying to transfer them through Pokebank and Pokemon Home. This happens, iirc, when trying to tranfer Mew from Pokemon Red/Blue

Comment: I didn't know that... I wonder what happens for the lucky few who got Mew through legitimate means all those years ago (Mew was handed out at Nintendo events)?

Comment: Old 1st and 2nd generations, meaning Pokemon RBY and GSC, aren't transferable on 3rd generation games, because Gameboy couldn't connect with GBA. So only legitimate Pokemon that may have transfered to these days are, at most, from Pokemon RSE

Comment: They can be traded from the first-generation games forwards as long as one is using the 'digital' (Virtual Console) version of the first-generation games, as per the Reddit post I linked to... I have changed the wording on my question slightly to reflect this.

Comment: In that case, yes. But you wrote "Mew was handed out at Nintendo events", and I thought you were talking about original physical games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [list of Nintendo events](https://www.serebii.net/events/dex/493.shtml) where one could have obtained Arceus. They are not limited to America, though many of them occur there or in Japan, and to a lesser degree Europe. As they are all legal, they can be transferred forward from their respective game into Pokemon Home or Pokemon Ultra Sun/Moon (the most recent games where they are currently legally obtainable, as Brilliant Diamond / Shining Pearl do not yet have Home access).

Arceus captured at the Sky Pillar [cannot be transferred to Home](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1xccxi/games_why_cant_my_arceus_transfer_through_pokebank/), even if it is not directly hacked. It is very unlikely that Arceus from an emulator can be transferred over given that emulators don't have access to event Arceus.

Comment: This answers my question... Thanks!